# Use gnuplot to draw the maximum point

Tags: graph, charts, plot, gnuplot, heatmap

I have a surface heat map and want to draw a point on the maximum value. The data file has 3 columns, x, y and z. I want to plot a point at the x and y coordinates where the value of z is a maximum. This is what I currently have:

```
set style data lines
set dgrid3d 20,200
set pm3d map
splot "d.dat" u 1:2:3
```

How can I plot a point at GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

- First draw the gridded data which you get with `set dgrid3d` to a temporary file using `set table`.
- Use `stats` to get the maximum value (the `splot` inside the `set table` doesn't set the `GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX` variable).
- Plot the tabulated data `with image` to get your heatmap. Using this plotting style instead of `pm3d` makes sure, that the maximum value is located centered in a 'pixel'.
- Plot a point only when the third column in the tabulated data corresponds to the maximum value.

The complete script:

```
set dgrid3d 20,200

set table 'd.table'
splot 'd.dat' u 1:2:3
unset table

stats 'd.table' u 3 nooutput

unset dgrid3d
set autoscale fix
unset key
plot 'd.table' with image,\
     '' using 1:($3 == STATS_max ? $2 : NaN) with points pt 7
```

Using an example file

```
0 0 5
0 1 7
0 2 9

1 0 2
1 1 0
1 2 10

2 0 1
2 1 1
2 2 8
```

and `set dgrid3d 4,4` gives you the following output (using 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: I get 2 errors with your commands. The first is on your 2nd statement: "Tabular output of this 3D plot style not implemented". The second is on the 5th statement: ""d.plot", line 7: No valid data points found in file", which is probably caused by the first error.

Comment: Don't worry, my problem was that my data in d.dat was seperated by tabs instead of spaces. Thanks it works now.

Comment: Might be a different question, but in addition to the point, I want to plot the x, y an z values of the maximum point, right next to the red dot. How does one do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a better solution (in my opinion) that directly reads the values from file a plots the point. Only works on Linux:

```
input = "d.dat"

# Calculate max values
maxz = real(system(sprintf("awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if (NR > 2 && $3 > max) max = $3} END {print max}' %s", input)))
maxx = real(system(sprintf("awk '$3 ~ %g { print $1 }' %s", maxz, input)))
maxy = real(system(sprintf("awk '$3 ~ %g { print $2 }' %s", maxz, input)))

# Plot point
set label 1 " " center front at maxx,maxy point pt 7 ps 1
```

Comment: Also a nice solution.